# Why is Storage Spaces created in GUI slower than when made by Powershell?

Tags: windows-10, raid, storage-spaces

I created a Storage Space on Windows 10 using the Storage Spaces GUI and found that the read/write speeds are very slow.  A dynamic stripe created in Disk Utility is about 3x faster.  I repeated this process a few times and got the same results.  So then I tried creating the same Storage Space using Powershell, and this way the read/write speeds are fast as they should be.  Why doesn't this work using the Storage Spaces GUI?

Here is the working Powershell code:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PhysicalDisks = (Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True)
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-StoragePool -FriendlyName stripe -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -PhysicalDisks $PhysicalDisks

FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly    Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------    ---- -------------
stripe       OK                Healthy      False        False      5.24 TB        768 MB


PS C:\Windows\system32> New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName stripe -FriendlyName stripe -ResiliencySettingName Simple -UseMaximumSize

FriendlyName ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy OperationalStatus HealthStatus    Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------ --------------------- --------------------- ----------------- ------------    ---- --------------- -----------------
stripe       Simple                0                     OK                Healthy      5.23 TB         5.23 TB            99.98%


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName stripe | Get-Disk | Initialize-Disk -Passthru | New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem ntfs

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining    Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------    ----
D                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      5.23 TB 5.23 TB
```

I've read that Storage Spaces is the modern way to create a RAID 0 Windows 10.  But when I create a simple pool (no resiliency), the read/write speed is very slow, compared with the old way of making a striped RAID in Disk Management.

Powershell method: 17500 MBps read, 3666 MBps write
Storage Spaces GUI method: 7171 MBps read, 1319 MBps write

I'm using three [Kioxia KCD6XLUL1T92](https://business.kioxia.com/nl-nl/ssd/data-center-ssd/cd6-r.html), so based on their specs the Disk Management stripe is right on target.  The Storage Space is only slightly better than single disk speed.

Here are photos of the process to create the Storage Space:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nice write up,

I'm not uber versed on soft raid but I'm pretty sure you need to set columns for each physical drive to get the performance benefits with striping RAID 0. By default, I think Windows Storage spaces doesn't count and apply a setting in the GUI.

When I build Windows Storage Spaces arrays, I use the -NumberOfColumns 2 command usually (if I'm boosting a dual SSD configuration to have insane read speed in a laptop for example... hehe)

For example :

***New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName DataRAID0 -StoragePoolFriendlyName "Data RAID0" -NumberOfColumns 2 -ResiliencySettingName simple -UseMaximumSize***

works pretty neatly and gives a much better performance (Like 2x) from what I saw on my crystalmark throughput scores, just bail on creating the storage array as soon as you drive select and then configure the coumn parameter with your favorite powershell.